# Positioning a clip-path without positioning the clipped element

Tags: html, css, svg, clip, clip-path

I'm struggeling to position an element using `clip-path: url(#clipdiv)`. 
Essentially I want to create **two overlapping images**, one with a `clip-path` overlapping the background element without one. On `:hover` I then want to show the background image, filling the viewport.

I don't have any problem positioning the two elements. However, the `clip-path` always starts on the very left of the page and is not responsive. **Adjusting `viewBox` doesn't change anything.**

Here a visual representation:

[image]

Of course I could move and scale the `clip-path` using css, but then the two elements won't be overlapping anymore.

This is my `clip-path` svg:

```
// It does exactly the same thing without the generated things in the svg tag.
// It seems like clip-path doesn't care about those.

<svg id="svg-clip" enable-background="new 0 0 1274.57 1034.27" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1274.57 1034.27" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <clippath id="logoclip">
      <path d="m432.81 1034.2c-3.27 0-5.8-0.26-8.25 0.07-2.7 0.37-4.98-1.22-7.59-1.1-2.55 0.12-4.84-1.27-7.27-1.68-7.01-1.17-13.1-4.59-19.37-7.55-2.8-1.32-5.6-2.92-7.91-4.96-4.24-3.75-9.22-6.57-13.04-10.86-5.97-6.69-11.63-13.56-16.43-21.18-3.75-5.96-6.6-12.22-8.99-18.79-1-2.75-2.13-5.44-3.05-8.24-1.16-3.56-1.92-7.2-2.84-10.8-1.06-4.14-2.34-8.28-2.04-12.66-2.2-3.09-0.54-6.81-1.77-10.25-1.1-3.11 0.17-6.97-0.3-10.41-1.9-13.67-0.64-27.4-0.87-41.09-0.24-13.83-0.05-27.66-0.05-41.49v-41.5-40.99-41.49-41.49s-0.76-27.71 0.19-41.48c1.25-18.05 0.54-36.06 0.76-54.09 0.22-18.16 0.05-36.33 0.05-54.49v-54.99-54.49s0-36.33 0-54.49c2.01-13.15 0.74-26.39 0.95-39.58 0.22-13.49 0.05-26.99 0.05-40.49v-39.99s0-26.66 0-39.99 0-26.66 0-39.99v-40.49c0-13.33 0.07-26.66-0.05-39.99-0.03-3.62 1.01-6.79 2.51-9.98 2.62-5.57 5.02-11.25 7.54-16.87 1.64-3.65 3.55-7.21 4.93-10.95 1.49-4.03 3.97-7.49 6.42-10.79 3.63-4.89 8.99-7.99 14.61-10.34 3.26-1.37 6.66-2.42 10.03-3.53 2.35-0.78 4.7-1.6 7.12-2.09 2.46-0.49 4.81-1.46 7.42-1.5 1.81-0.03 3.6-0.88 5.39-1.37 0.6-0.16 1.17-0.46 1.78-0.52 3.52-0.37 7.08-0.52 10.56-1.08 2.03-0.33 3.95-1.05 6.09-1.01 1.85 0.03 3.71-0.74 5.58-0.89 2.15-0.17 4.44 0.41 6.47-0.12 9.46-2.47 19.08-1.88 28.67-1.91 9.82-0.04 19.65-0.05 29.47 0.04 1.53 0.01 3.05 0.64 4.58 0.95 1.38 0.28 2.94-0.57 4.19 0.83 0.31 0.35 1.25 0.18 1.89 0.17 5-0.13 9.87 0.5 14.68 1.95 1.37 0.41 2.99-0.06 4.47 0.1 1.22 0.14 2.37 0.74 3.59 0.94 9.75 1.59 19 4.63 27.27 10.1 1.59 1.05 2.97 3.08 3.48 4.93 0.47 1.69 2.59 3.74 0.15 5.63 0.04 6.39-3.62 11.48-6 17.01-2.62 6.08-5.14 12.22-8.05 18.15-2.01 4.1-3.05 8.13-3.03 12.79 0.16 36.66 0.09 73.32 0.09 109.98-2.03 15.66-0.73 31.38-0.95 47.08-0.22 15.99-0.05 31.99-0.05 47.99v47.49 47.49 47.99c0 15.83 0.82 31.72-0.23 47.48-1.06 15.89-0.47 31.73-0.72 47.59-0.25 15.83-0.05 31.66-0.05 47.49v47.99 47.99 47.49c0 16 0.78 32.04-0.22 47.98-0.96 15.22-0.52 30.4-0.73 45.59-0.21 15.16-0.05 30.33-0.05 45.49v45.99c-1.5 6.47-0.42 13.1-1.19 19.56-0.42 3.55-0.62 7.06-0.84 10.6-0.11 1.71-0.61 3.4-0.96 5.09-0.38 1.85 0.5 3.71-0.84 5.69-0.85 1.26 0.31 3.72-0.24 5.36-2.05 6.06-1.9 12.65-4.8 18.51-0.87 1.76-0.33 4.23-1.22 5.98-3.21 6.33-5.08 13.27-8.88 19.33-3.35 5.35-6.82 10.59-10.72 15.58-3.47 4.44-7.35 8.44-11.47 12.16-5.17 4.67-10.61 9.05-16.76 12.5-5.29 2.97-10.72 5.4-16.55 7.14-2.06 0.62-4.18 1.16-6.25 1.74-2.11 0.59-4.49 0.7-6.51 1.26-4.9 1.3-9.77 0.33-13.85 0.77zm66.89-1011.1c0.1-0.27 0.19-0.53 0.29-0.8-1.96-1.35-3.76-3.15-5.92-3.98-5.87-2.25-12.14-2.96-18.3-4.01-2.75-0.47-5.65-0.08-8.48-0.08h-8.49c-3 0-6.01-0.16-8.99 0.05-2.72 0.19-5.42-0.57-8.21 0.66-2.41 1.07-5.47-0.34-7.96 1.29-4.69-0.22-8.96 1.52-13.23 3.04-6.29 2.24-11.6 5.72-14.45 12.18-1.49 3.39-3.74 6.49-4.85 9.98-1.18 3.72-3.37 6.91-4.61 10.61-1.62 4.78-4.33 9.19-6.47 13.8-0.73 1.57-1.08 3.23-1.08 5.07 0.08 18.33 0.05 36.66 0.05 54.99s0 36.66 0 54.99c0 18.5 0.18 37-0.05 55.49-0.23 18.19 0.43 36.37-0.75 54.59-0.99 15.27-0.2 30.65-0.2 45.98v46.49 45.99 46.49c0 15.33 0.19 30.66-0.05 45.99-0.24 15.36 0.18 30.7-0.7 46.09-1.05 18.44-0.25 36.98-0.25 55.48v55.99 55.49c0 18.66 0.18 37.33-0.05 55.99-0.23 18.36 0.32 36.71-0.71 55.09-0.85 15.13-0.99 30.39 0.69 45.57 0.47 4.28 0.07 8.66 0.07 12.99 0 2.5-0.52 5.15 0.15 7.45 0.61 2.08 1.1 4.1 0.77 6.12-0.37 2.25 1.09 4.02 1.07 6.1-0.04 3.69 1.04 7.19 2.06 10.65 1.52 5.17 3.11 10.26 5.78 15.11 3.69 6.7 8.71 11.88 14.74 16.26 3.15 2.29 6.74 3.96 10.46 4.83 4.07 0.95 8.31 1.09 12.55 1.22 8.51 0.24 15.8-3.04 22.26-7.77 5.15-3.77 9.19-8.96 12.16-14.85 3.32-6.59 4.67-11.73 6.07-18.01 1.17-5.24 1.52-10.58 2.7-15.82 0.87-3.87 0.41-8.01 1-12.07 0.82-5.61 0.09-11.35 0.98-17.09 0.81-5.21 0.17-10.64 0.17-15.97s0-10.66 0-16 0.23-10.68-0.07-15.99c-0.3-5.27 0.99-10.39 1.03-15.59 0.1-14 0.03-27.99 0.03-41.99v-41.49-41.99s0-27.99 0-41.99c0-13.83-0.18-27.66 0.05-41.49 0.24-13.86-1.11-27.76 0.95-41.58v-66.49-66.49c0-22.33-0.16-44.66 0.05-66.99 0.2-22.03-1.02-44.07 0.95-66.07v-187.96-50.81c2.05-4.17 4.48-8.03 5.84-12.25 0.97-3.01 2.54-5.63 3.75-8.46 1.27-2.97 2.56-5.94 3.89-8.89 1.14-2.53 2.43-4.99 3.46-7.56 0.46-1.14-0.09-2.43 0.62-3.76 0.5-0.87-0.45-2.52-0.77-3.82z"/>
      <path d="m54.27 118.23v156.74h-53.5c-0.77-4.33-1.11-251.68-0.32-271.82h26.32 26.34c1.12 2.2 2.36 4.52 3.52 6.89 6.21 12.75 12.59 25.43 18.54 38.31 4.08 8.83 8.96 17.29 12.75 26.21 4.05 9.54 9.08 18.55 13.36 27.95 4.03 8.84 9.07 17.24 12.77 26.2 2.89 7 6.63 13.53 9.63 20.69 1.98-4.15 3.84-8.05 5.71-11.94 4.35-9.03 8.89-17.97 13.01-27.1 3.3-7.33 7.46-14.25 10.5-21.64 3.42-8.3 7.84-16.07 11.51-24.22 3.61-8.01 8.16-15.62 11.47-23.74 3.39-8.31 7.94-16.02 11.45-24.25 1.87-4.39 3.98-8.68 6.07-13.19h53.47v271.83h-26.26-26.31v-156.7c-0.23-0.06-0.46-0.12-0.69-0.18-2.82 5.64-5.64 11.29-8.45 16.94-3.43 6.91-6.56 13.99-10.34 20.7-11.38 20.2-20.64 41.48-31.63 61.88-0.37 0.68-0.67 1.39-1.05 2.19h-35.92c-1.22-2.43-2.56-5.23-4.02-7.96-12.68-23.69-24.24-47.94-36.56-71.81-3.61-7.01-7.23-14.02-11.37-21.98z"/>
      <path d="m2.45 374.24h52.66c2.03 3.8 4.34 7.51 6.07 11.48 4.96 11.31 10.75 22.21 15.93 33.39 4.15 8.97 9.08 17.58 12.93 26.63 4 9.39 9.14 18.19 13.13 27.55 3.82 8.96 8.82 17.34 12.7 26.23 3.02 6.94 6.62 13.58 9.78 20.74 4.89-10.07 9.73-19.97 14.52-29.89 5.02-10.41 10.17-20.77 14.94-31.3 3.44-7.6 7.66-14.84 10.87-22.49 3.66-8.7 8.43-16.83 12.13-25.47 3.29-7.68 7.44-14.92 10.84-22.51 2.14-4.77 4.53-9.44 6.56-14.37h53.44v271.43c-3.91 0.69-40.08 0.91-52.83 0.28v-157.59c-17.65 34.83-34.86 68.78-52.06 102.71h-35.73c-2.03-3.81-4.15-7.6-6.1-11.47-11.46-22.74-22.67-45.61-34.43-68.2-3.67-7.05-7.29-14.16-11.52-22.11v156.77h-53.82c-0.01-90.49-0.01-180.93-0.01-271.81z"/>
      <path d="m5.44 747.24h52.72c2.35 4.51 4.99 8.91 7.02 13.59 4.6 10.63 10.16 20.78 14.95 31.3 4.1 9 9.05 17.59 12.92 26.64 4.01 9.39 9.13 18.2 13.13 27.55 3.83 8.95 8.83 17.34 12.71 26.23 3.03 6.94 6.63 13.57 9.73 20.62 2.13-4.15 4.6-8.06 6.23-12.29 3.51-9.1 8.51-17.46 12.49-26.32 3.29-7.31 7.38-14.27 10.45-21.67 3.5-8.43 8.19-16.26 11.69-24.65 3.28-7.85 7.47-15.23 11.03-22.92 3.89-8.39 8.01-16.67 11.97-25.03 2.04-4.32 3.94-8.7 5.91-13.05h53.57v271.66h-52.87v-157.52c-17.63 34.79-34.84 68.75-52.03 102.66h-35.79c-2.27-4.38-4.58-8.76-6.82-13.17-10.96-21.62-21.87-43.26-32.87-64.86-3.88-7.63-7.96-15.16-12.16-23.14v155.72c-4.25 0.76-40.73 0.99-53.98 0.36v-271.71z"/>
      <path d="m915.81 112.82c0.53 0.53 0.88 0.88 1.4 1.41h106.22v46.72h-106.21c-0.51 0.62-0.92 1.13-1.49 1.83v64.23h125.58v48h-178.42v-271.73h178.43v46.79h-124.11l-1.4 1.4v61.35z"/>
      <path d="m865.17 374.15h177.84c0.75 4.04 0.98 33.12 0.35 46.84h-124.07l-1.66 1.66v58.88c0 1.32-0.31 2.76 2.52 3.62h105.24v46.86h-106.63c-0.44 1.1-1.03 1.94-1.08 2.81-0.14 2.32-0.05 4.66-0.05 7v56.29h125.81v47.87h-178.27c-0.69-3.73-0.72-267.55 0-271.83z"/>
      <path d="m920.8 856.82c0.52 0.52 0.87 0.88 1.32 1.32h53.32 52.98v47h-4.29c-32.8 0-65.61-0.01-98.41 0.02-1.72 0-3.73-0.75-5 1.45v64.39h125.58v48.01h-178.41v-271.72h178.42v46.78h-124.1l-1.4 1.4c-0.01 20.27-0.01 40.72-0.01 61.35z"/>
      <path d="m1068.8 241.38c5.73-5.74 10.89-10.9 16.05-16.07 5.53-5.54 11.08-11.07 16.6-16.63 0.95-0.96 1.81-1.97 2.98-1.62 3.13 2.61 5.89 5.13 8.88 7.34 3.75 2.76 7.67 5.2 12.14 6.87 3.9 1.46 7.75 3.03 11.78 4.13 2.09 0.57 4.17 1.21 6.28 1.73 1.67 0.41 3.37 0.76 5.08 0.99 1.56 0.21 3.16-0.26 4.64 0.94 0.6 0.49 1.93 0.08 2.93 0.08 7.33 0 14.66-0.03 21.98 0.01 6.42 0.04 12.43-1.73 18.49-3.62 5.33-1.66 9.9-4.39 13.4-8.6 3.53-4.25 6.43-8.93 6.44-14.83 0-1.2 0.74-2.37 0.92-3.59 0.17-1.14 0.24-2.37 0-3.49-0.98-4.43-0.95-9.05-2.85-13.31-3.49-7.84-9-11.94-16.74-14.51-4.75-1.58-9.57-2.95-14.71-3.24-2.48-0.14-5.22-0.28-7.53-1.02-2.45-0.78-5-0.07-7.08-0.96-2.44-1.05-5.01-0.09-7.08-1-2.44-1.07-4.8-0.45-7.14-0.9-4.04-0.78-8.04-1.75-12.17-1.96-1.46-2.2-3.94-0.37-5.89-1.54-1.59-0.95-3.7-1.85-5.86-1.46-5.87-3.09-12.24-4.96-18.04-8.4-6.87-4.07-12.5-9.34-17.61-15.14-4.08-4.64-6.87-10.28-9.28-16.1-1.61-3.9-2.03-8.12-3.89-11.89 0.66-3.14-1.02-6-1.05-9.09-0.03-3.2 0.48-6.41-0.8-9.64-0.53-1.35-0.8-3.45 0.61-5.16 0.58-0.71 0.22-2.22 0.24-3.36 0.15-11.54 3.21-22.3 8.69-32.4 2.81-5.18 5.9-10.17 10.23-14.27 2.06-1.95 4.02-3.99 6.01-6 3.83-3.89 8.45-6.66 13-9.61 5.92-3.84 12.38-6.34 19.04-8.35 3.57-1.08 7.16-2.22 10.92-2.62 1.55-0.16 3.05-0.72 4.59-0.95 1.4-0.21 2.91 0.35 4.13-0.97 0.31-0.33 1.28-0.01 1.94-0.06 5.02-0.36 10.15 0.9 15.09-0.96 0.58-0.22 1.43-0.26 1.97 0.01 3.59 1.76 7.4 0.7 11.1 0.95 2.3 0.15 4.88-0.48 6.84 0.37 2.35 1.03 5.01-0.42 6.61 0.8 2.05 1.56 4.74-0.4 6.29 1.84 6.75 0 12.71 3 18.89 5.07 5.41 1.81 10.55 4.25 15.51 7.22 4.58 2.74 8.84 5.91 13.36 8.72 0.27 0.17 0.52 0.38 0.76 0.59 2.29 2.03 4.57 4.07 6.91 6.16 0 0.05 0.01 0.22 0 0.39-0.02 0.15-0.01 0.36-0.1 0.45-11.06 11.09-22.13 22.16-33.24 33.28-7.84-7.17-17.04-11.87-27.16-14.87-3.32-0.99-6.86-1.34-10.09-2.27-3.53-1.01-6.99-0.25-10.45-1.16-3.25-0.85-6.84-0.6-10.28-0.52-2.37 0.05-4.72 0.6-7.08 0.95-2.2 0.32-4.42 0.52-6.57 1.04-2.24 0.54-4.47 1.25-6.58 2.18-1.56 0.68-2.86 1.91-4.35 2.77-7.23 4.17-10.98 10.95-13.86 18.38 0.08 4.54-2.82 9.05-0.13 13.62 0.11 6.15 3.5 10.84 7.5 14.83 3.99 3.98 9.07 6.66 14.57 8.11 3.64 0.96 7.27 1.93 11.14 2.21 4.89 0.35 9.75 1.42 14.65 2.04 2.17 0.28 4.52 0.27 6.57 0.93 2.23 0.72 4.49 0.42 6.6 0.97 4.41 1.14 8.93 1.81 13.35 2.59 6.52 1.15 12.71 3.06 18.81 5.37 6.4 2.42 12.62 5.28 17.97 9.69 2.12 1.75 4.31 3.42 6.28 5.32 5.42 5.23 9.26 11.55 12.51 18.3 1.29 2.68 1.97 5.52 2.93 8.29 0.92 2.65 1.59 5.38 2.26 8.1 0.66 2.71-0.04 5.57 1.12 7.99 1.26 2.61 0.39 5.18 0.59 7.75 0.22 2.82 0.05 5.66 0.05 8.5 0 2.67 0.49 5.45-0.1 7.98-1.43 6.2-2.19 12.48-4.6 18.57-2.56 6.43-6.04 12.21-9.48 18.06-0.98 1.67-2.63 3.05-4.21 4.23-1.37 1.02-1.74 2.67-3.35 3.67-2.71 1.68-4.78 4.3-7.37 6.32-8.84 6.88-18.72 11.56-29.2 15.24-4.39 1.54-8.95 2.48-13.39 3.82-3.48 1.05-7.4 0.51-11.02 1.2-10.66 2.01-21.39 0.47-32.08 0.88-2.34 0.09-4.72-0.58-7.08-0.94-2.19-0.34-4.34 0.17-6.67-0.79-2.02-0.83-4.65-0.75-7.01-1.11-7.26-1.11-18.16-4.28-26.38-7.54-4.18-1.65-8.22-3.58-12.14-5.66-5.97-3.17-11.74-6.77-16.79-11.38-3.02-2.72-6.19-5.26-9.74-8.28z"/>
      <path d="m1071.5 612.56c11.52-11.53 22.78-22.8 34.38-34.41h0.65c2.85 2.34 5.55 4.65 8.35 6.84 3.94 3.09 8.18 5.5 12.96 7.32 5.07 1.93 10.1 3.78 15.35 5.21 2.26 0.61 4.59 0.72 6.85 1.48 2.82 0.95 6 0.94 9.03 1.11 2.99 0.17 5.99 0.04 8.99 0.04 4.83 0 9.69 0.35 14.48-0.08 7.48-0.67 14.71-2.41 21.54-5.86 7.47-3.76 11.37-10.17 14.3-17.5-0.49-3.93 2.01-7.68 0.99-11.54-1.12-4.23-0.89-8.72-2.88-12.8-3.69-7.57-8.94-11.55-16.56-14.14-4.73-1.61-9.58-2.86-14.71-3.22-4.89-0.34-9.69-1.88-14.67-1.86-2.19-1.57-4.94-0.28-7.02-1.15-2.44-1.03-4.86-0.3-7.12-0.92-4.39-1.21-9.08-0.93-13.31-2.82-3.63 0.55-6.73-1.5-10.09-2.23-3.41-0.74-6.61-2.49-9.9-3.78-10.71-4.19-19.43-11.22-26.66-19.9-3.93-4.72-6.78-10.3-9.1-16.18-1.49-3.78-2.22-7.72-3.59-11.5-1.07-2.93-0.87-6.32-1.2-9.51-0.32-3.03 0.44-6.08-0.84-9.15-0.55-1.31-0.9-3.51 0.55-5.17 0.43-0.49 0.38-1.58 0.27-2.35-0.63-4.45 0.25-8.89 1.2-13.05 1.85-8.11 4.71-15.9 9.03-23.25 4.56-7.77 10.89-13.75 17.2-19.79 3.02-2.9 6.96-4.82 10.43-7.26 3.58-2.51 7.55-4.25 11.56-5.88 4.3-1.76 8.82-2.87 13.28-4.13 4.69-1.32 9.55-1.73 14.29-2.83 3.32-0.77 6.96-0.07 10.46-0.18 1.72-0.06 3.5 0.61 5.17-0.87 0.65-0.58 2.52-0.53 3.36-0.01 2.48 1.54 5.13 1.04 7.62 0.83 5.45-0.46 10.85 0.32 16.05 1.26 10.05 1.81 19.91 4.45 29.49 8.32 7.58 3.06 14.23 7.55 21.18 11.58 2.62 1.52 4.7 3.93 7.07 5.9 1.55 1.29 3.17 2.5 4.52 3.56-11.41 11.42-22.56 22.58-33.94 33.96-4.52-5.12-11.24-8.19-17.77-11.39-3.98-1.95-8.37-3.16-12.77-4.16-4.85-1.09-9.73-1.6-14.65-2.14-3.2-0.35-6.39-0.9-9.6-0.76-3.87 0.16-7.77 0.36-11.57 1.04-3.65 0.65-7.24 1.76-10.74 2.99-1.72 0.6-3.19 1.94-4.78 2.93-8.15 5.07-10.83 10.57-13.9 18.29-0.01 4.53-2.92 9.01-0.21 13.58-0.23 5.48 2.96 9.63 6.03 13.45 3.37 4.2 8.21 6.86 13.33 8.64 4.6 1.6 9.2 3.41 14.24 3.03 2.21 1.39 4.84 0.43 7.04 1.13 2.4 0.78 4.9 0.28 7.08 1.01 2.41 0.8 4.91 0.27 7.08 1 2.25 0.76 4.54 0.32 6.6 0.95 4.37 1.33 9.11 0.81 13.28 2.9 6.89 0.03 13.17 2.85 19.33 5.22 6.14 2.36 12.3 5.23 17.49 9.71 2.07 1.79 4.28 3.43 6.24 5.37 4.78 4.74 8.3 10.34 11.3 16.32 2.48 4.95 4.71 13.19 5.95 18.05 2.76 10.82 2.01 21.79 1.73 32.69-0.12 4.57-1.48 9.24-2.8 13.77-1.3 4.48-3.37 8.62-5.43 12.75-2.57 5.13-5.56 10-9.87 13.91-1.46 1.33-2.32 3.14-4.12 4.27-1.79 1.12-3.02 3.09-4.68 4.47-1.56 1.3-3.37 2.3-5.04 3.47-1.68 1.18-3.2 2.69-5.02 3.58-6.92 3.37-13.65 7.15-21.07 9.47-4.43 1.39-8.96 2.44-13.4 3.8-3.47 1.06-7.41 0.48-11.02 1.21-9.33 1.87-18.72 0.58-28.08 0.86-3.01 0.09-6.02 0.52-9.14-0.77-2.71-1.12-6.16 0.75-9.01-1.16-4.72 0.46-9.1-1.43-13.64-2.15-4.84-0.77-9.55-2.57-14.21-4.21-6.55-2.3-12.86-5.2-18.91-8.63-5.5-3.12-10.69-6.64-15.6-10.68-3.15-2.58-6.09-5.26-8.7-7.9z"/>
      <path d="m1267.6 775.8c-11.57 11.58-22.74 22.75-33.93 33.96-7.35-6.91-16.51-11.45-26.41-14.55-3.43-1.08-6.89-2.48-10.64-2.06-3.18-2.18-6.91-0.5-10.37-1.45-3.24-0.89-6.85-0.57-10.29-0.49-2.37 0.06-4.72 0.6-7.08 0.95-2.2 0.32-4.43 0.51-6.57 1.04-2.24 0.55-4.41 1.38-6.58 2.2-0.86 0.32-1.7 0.82-2.41 1.41-3.48 2.92-7.67 4.91-10.22 9.06-2.64 4.31-4.85 8.57-5.79 13.65-0.54 2.89-1.34 5.84-0.68 8.57 0.45 1.89 0.73 3.72 0.83 5.43 1.97 2.65 3.13 5.6 4.8 8.24 2.2 3.47 5.32 5.42 8.51 7.34 6.1 3.67 12.75 5.66 19.95 6.23 2.49 0.2 5.21 0.25 7.54 0.99 2.43 0.77 4.96 0.17 7.07 0.99 2.27 0.88 4.57 0.27 6.6 0.97 2.23 0.77 4.5 0.41 6.6 0.97 4.4 1.18 9.1 0.86 13.3 2.84 6.69 0.22 12.76 2.86 18.86 5.14 6.4 2.39 12.61 5.3 17.96 9.71 1.99 1.64 4.04 3.21 5.93 4.97 5.19 4.82 8.82 10.77 12.02 17.01 2.13 4.16 4.48 13.29 5.93 18.06 0.83 2.73-0.01 5.54 1.19 7.98 1.28 2.58 0.38 5.18 0.57 7.75 0.21 2.82 0.05 5.66 0.05 8.5 0 2.67 0.5 5.45-0.1 7.98-1.46 6.19-2.16 12.48-4.64 18.56-2.61 6.4-5.89 12.3-9.52 18.04-1.76 2.78-4.21 5.33-6.86 7.28-2.61 1.92-4.05 5.21-7.41 6.16-5.78 5.49-12.9 8.71-19.98 12.08-5.49 2.62-11.31 4.09-17.02 5.98-4.05 1.34-8.36 1.25-12.29 2.87-0.28 0.12-0.66-0.01-0.99 0.02-3.86 0.33-7.71 0.8-11.58 0.96-3.99 0.17-7.99 0.04-11.99 0.04-2.33 0-4.69-0.21-6.99 0.04-5.77 0.64-11.41-0.76-17.06-1.29-4.39-0.41-8.91-1.44-13.33-2.53-3.61-0.89-7.38-1.5-10.95-2.62-8.39-2.64-16.58-5.84-24.25-10.2-5.77-3.28-11.43-6.7-16.33-11.28-2.83-2.65-5.91-5.03-8.84-7.49 1.38-2.02 32.06-33.51 33.67-34.51 0.49-0.3 1.28-0.12 1.63-0.14 3.28 2.79 6.15 5.76 9.53 7.96 3.6 2.34 7.18 4.74 11.41 6.21 3.92 1.36 7.76 2.98 11.77 4.14 1.93 0.56 3.83 1.44 5.79 1.64 5.08 0.51 9.97 2.24 15.16 2.09 5.33-0.15 10.66-0.03 15.99-0.03 1.33 0 2.67-0.07 4 0.01 4.76 0.29 11.33-1.56 18.47-3.67 5.03-1.49 9.3-4.03 12.71-7.87 3.92-4.42 6.99-9.28 7.11-15.56 0.04-2.18 1.3-4.27 0.94-6.59-0.7-4.51-0.96-9.15-2.67-13.4-3.13-7.75-9.25-12.41-17.02-14.87-4.78-1.51-9.58-2.92-14.72-3.24-2.3-0.14-4.85-0.27-7.05-0.95-2.41-0.75-4.89-0.28-7.08-0.99-2.57-0.84-5.31-0.17-7.56-1.04-2.46-0.95-4.89-0.21-7.12-0.91-4.36-1.37-9.13-0.73-13.27-2.92-3.68 0.81-6.88-1.22-10.11-2.18-6.01-1.8-11.95-4.11-17.41-7.38-5.84-3.5-11.05-7.75-15.74-12.7-5.51-5.81-9.45-12.42-12.29-19.93-1.9-5.04-2.99-10.13-4.06-15.35-0.74-3.59-0.59-7.08-0.83-10.62-0.07-1.09-0.18-2.1-0.66-3.22-0.64-1.51-0.74-3.81 0.01-5.2 0.81-1.52 0.59-2.85 0.63-4.25 0.29-11.68 3.28-22.59 9.01-32.78 2.81-5.01 5.8-9.85 9.98-13.87 4.02-3.86 7.78-7.98 12.28-11.35 3.23-2.41 12.6-7.53 16.67-9.25 2.99-1.26 5.98-2.58 9.09-3.35 3.63-0.91 7.15-2.3 10.94-2.6 1.54-0.12 3.04-0.74 4.59-0.93 1.41-0.18 2.89 0.22 4.13-0.98 0.34-0.33 1.29-0.02 1.95-0.06 5.03-0.3 10.14 0.8 15.08-0.97 0.44-0.16 1.04-0.16 1.48 0 5.11 1.83 10.39 0.59 15.58 1.01 1.88 0.15 3.72 0.65 5.58 0.97 1.7 0.29 3.36-0.26 5.18 0.83 1.41 0.84 3.67 0.78 5.5 1.01 4.25 0.54 8.22 1.85 12.23 3.16 6.61 2.15 13.17 4.37 19.19 7.98 4.84 2.9 9.85 5.5 14.18 9.22 3.03 2.55 6.26 4.88 9.52 7.42z"/>
      <path d="m610.85 3.18h54.81c0.66 1.48 1.94 3.12 2.04 4.83 0.26 4.35 2.74 7.95 3.53 12.07 1.05 5.5 3.73 10.52 4.66 16.09 0.48 2.84 2.1 5.47 2.87 8.28 1.79 6.57 3.97 13.02 6.03 19.5 2.3 7.21 4.57 14.45 6.7 21.69 2.05 6.98 4.49 13.85 6.37 20.89 1.87 7.01 4.67 13.77 6.47 20.79 1.59 6.17 3.8 12.12 5.51 18.23 1.95 6.99 4.59 13.78 6.5 20.78 1.1 4.02 2.29 7.97 3.87 12.18 1.41-4.36 2.97-8.26 3.92-12.3 1.28-5.45 3.78-10.5 4.72-16.07 0.48-2.84 2.15-5.46 2.86-8.28 1.97-7.82 4.88-15.33 7.09-23.07 1.99-6.98 4.67-13.77 6.49-20.78 1.6-6.16 3.81-12.11 5.52-18.23 1.95-6.99 4.68-13.76 6.48-20.78 1.59-6.17 3.8-12.12 5.51-18.23 1.95-6.99 4.59-13.78 6.51-20.78 1.28-4.64 2.64-9.21 4.37-13.69 0.32-0.84 0.05-1.91 0.05-3h55.98c-0.35 1.82-0.38 3.73-1.07 5.36-4.14 9.69-6.36 20-9.87 29.9-4.03 11.35-7.47 22.89-11.28 34.32-3.85 11.56-7.9 23.05-11.75 34.62-4.15 12.45-8.13 24.95-12.25 37.41-4.55 13.77-9.04 27.57-13.78 41.28-5.45 15.75-10.26 31.71-15.71 47.46-4.28 12.39-8.54 24.83-12.25 37.42-0.39 1.33-0.9 2.62-1.38 4.02h-40.5c-1.36-4.45-2.67-8.89-4.09-13.3-3.71-11.46-7.42-22.91-11.23-34.34-3.51-10.53-7.32-20.97-10.7-31.55-3.01-9.42-6.46-18.69-9.19-28.2-0.84-2.93-1.55-5.96-2.79-8.83-1.28-2.96-2.04-6.15-3.07-9.23-0.97-2.93-2.01-5.83-2.99-8.76-4.2-12.59-8.36-25.19-12.57-37.78-4.07-12.14-7.74-24.41-12.35-36.37-0.6-6.44-3.73-12.14-5.38-18.28-1.64-6.1-3.89-12.04-5.93-18.03-2.88-8.47-5.83-16.91-8.72-25.38-0.14-0.45-0.01-0.98-0.01-1.86z"/>
      <path d="m612.41 374.25h55.33c0.69 1.56 1.91 3.09 1.97 4.66 0.16 4.2 2.31 7.78 3.32 11.69 0.71 2.74 1.58 5.63 2.58 8.39 0.98 2.7 1.93 5.57 2.43 8.56 0.46 2.74 1.94 5.49 2.74 8.3 1.9 6.7 3.99 13.35 6.14 19.96 2.24 6.9 4.25 13.87 6.54 20.76 1.75 5.26 3.61 10.55 5.02 15.91 1.19 4.52 3.03 8.82 4.13 13.27 1.08 4.41 3 8.52 3.95 12.86 0.98 4.45 2.96 8.53 3.93 12.88 0.98 4.43 2.94 8.52 3.93 12.88 1.41 6.22 3.9 12.1 5.4 18.28 0.54 2.23 1.5 4.37 2.32 6.71 3.44-8.54 4.93-17.46 8.59-25.66 0.67-6.25 3.45-11.91 5.12-17.88 2.25-8.03 5.34-15.82 7.49-23.86 1.64-6.15 3.76-12.13 5.48-18.25 1.96-6.98 4.71-13.75 6.53-20.77 1.6-6.16 3.75-12.14 5.47-18.25 1.96-6.98 4.73-13.75 6.54-20.76 1.59-6.17 3.94-12.08 5.41-18.27 0.57-2.41 1.38-4.76 2.1-7.12 0.41-1.33 0.86-2.65 1.37-4.22h55.45c-0.32 1.72-0.33 3.63-1.04 5.22-1.77 3.98-2.95 8.12-4.14 12.29-1.15 4.01-2.51 7.95-3.79 11.92-1.33 4.12-2.64 8.23-4 12.34-3.74 11.28-7.47 22.56-11.25 33.83-3.54 10.53-7.21 21.01-10.71 31.55-4.14 12.45-8.12 24.96-12.24 37.42-3.87 11.72-7.83 23.41-11.76 35.11-1.47 4.39-3.19 8.7-4.43 13.15-2.77 9.98-6.39 19.69-9.58 29.53-3.43 10.57-7.07 21.06-10.58 31.6-1.95 5.86-3.83 11.75-5.79 17.77h-40.48c-1.35-4.34-2.67-8.78-4.1-13.18-4.05-12.48-8.1-24.97-12.22-37.43-3.87-11.72-7.82-23.42-11.76-35.12-2.42-7.17-5.21-14.22-6.99-21.6-2.04-1.19-0.33-3.63-1.88-5.29-1.13-1.2-1.09-3.48-1.61-5.27-0.48-1.63-0.96-3.27-1.52-4.87-0.61-1.74-1.4-3.42-1.97-5.18-3.1-9.55-6.07-19.14-9.23-28.67-3.5-10.54-7.2-21.01-10.75-31.53-2.23-6.58-4.64-13.11-6.46-19.81-2.47-9.12-5.86-17.92-8.61-26.94-2.88-9.44-6.3-18.71-9.46-28.06-0.97-2.78-1.86-5.58-2.93-8.85z"/>
      <path d="m615.75 747.26h54.92c0.68 1.44 1.98 2.96 2.03 4.52 0.11 4.22 2.21 7.83 3.32 11.69 0.79 2.74 1.46 5.66 2.54 8.41 1.03 2.62 2.13 5.48 2.4 8.56 0.24 2.82 1.93 5.49 2.82 8.27 2.06 6.48 4.02 13 6.01 19.5 2.14 6.95 4.31 13.88 6.39 20.84 1.68 5.62 3.17 11.31 5.6 16.68-0.38 3.3 1.66 6 2.26 9.08 0.56 2.85 1.83 5.56 2.73 8.35 2.27 7.06 4.44 14.16 6.59 21.25 2.16 7.1 4.39 14.2 6.44 21.34 1.57 5.49 3.39 10.9 5.21 16.68 3.68-8.59 5.01-17.5 8.61-25.66 0.25-5.24 3.06-9.75 4.23-14.76 1.12-4.79 3.11-9.37 4.57-14.08 0.92-2.97 1.47-6.05 2.36-9.03 0.88-2.95 2.02-5.83 2.96-8.77 2.28-7.06 4.07-14.26 6.66-21.23 1.08-2.9 1.48-6.04 2.37-9.02 0.88-2.95 2.02-5.83 2.96-8.77 2.28-7.06 4.45-14.16 6.58-21.25 1.82-6.08 3.78-12.12 5.49-18.24 1.95-6.98 4.45-13.81 6.63-20.73 0.33-1.05 0.28-2.22 0.43-3.55h56.14c-14.46 45.66-29.9 90.74-44.92 135.96-14.99 45.12-29.74 90.32-44.66 135.67h-40.54c-1.32-4.18-2.69-8.61-4.11-13.01-4.38-13.51-8.74-27.03-13.19-40.52-4.54-13.77-9.17-27.52-13.79-41.27-1.47-4.38-3.29-8.67-4.5-13.12-2.4-8.81-5.57-17.35-8.46-25.99-3.18-9.52-6.1-19.13-9.27-28.65-3.5-10.54-7.27-20.99-10.68-31.56-1.43-4.41-3-8.77-4.23-13.26-1.25-4.6-2.8-9.14-4.46-13.63-1.6-4.34-2.91-8.79-4.37-13.19-3.84-11.57-7.71-23.13-11.54-34.7-0.27-0.86-0.34-1.79-0.53-2.81z"/>
   </clippath>
</svg>
```

And this is the layout:

```
<img id="logoVideo" src="https://images.vice.com/motherboard/content-images/article/20449/1427798070375676.jpg">
<div class="logo-box">
   <svg id="svg-clip" enable-background="new 0 0 1274.57 1034.27" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1274.57 1034.27" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <clippath id="logoclip">
        // The whole SVG is above
      </clippath>
   </svg>
<div>
```

In a css file I style `#logoVideo` with `clip-path: url(#logoclip)`.

I hope someone here is smart enough. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: can you post full code? this way it will be easier to help you

Comment: @SergeyRudenko I've added the rest